# Solr 6.0.0 - SolrCloud java example

Tags: solr

I have solr installed on my localhost.

I started **standard solr cloud example** with embedded zookeepr.

collection: gettingstarted
shards: 2
replication : 2

**500 records/docs to process time took 115 seconds[localhost tetsing] - 
why is this taking this much time to process just 500 records.
is there a way to improve this to some millisecs/nanosecs**

NOTE:

I have tested the same on remote machine solr instance, localhost having data index on remote solr [inside java commented]

I started **my solr myCloudData collection** with Ensemble with single zookeepr.

**2 solr nodes,
1 Ensemble zookeeper standalone**

collection: myCloudData,
shards: 2,
replication : 2

Solr colud java code

```
package com.test.solr.basic;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;

 public class SolrjPopulatorCloudClient2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws     IOException,SolrServerException {           


    //String zkHosts = "64.101.49.57:2181/solr";
    String zkHosts = "localhost:9983";
    CloudSolrClient solrCloudClient = new CloudSolrClient(zkHosts, true);
    //solrCloudClient.setDefaultCollection("myCloudData");
    solrCloudClient.setDefaultCollection("gettingstarted");
    /*
    // Thread Safe
    solrClient = new ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient(urlString, queueSize, threadCount);
    */
    // Depreciated - client
    //HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
        SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
        doc.addField("cat", "book");
        doc.addField("id", "book-" + i);
        doc.addField("name", "The Legend of the Hobbit part " + i);
        solrCloudClient.add(doc);
        if (i % 100 == 0)
            System.out.println(" Every 100 records flush it");
        solrCloudClient.commit(); // periodically flush
    }
    solrCloudClient.commit(); 
    solrCloudClient.close();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long seconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(end - start);
    System.out.println(" All records are indexed, took " + seconds + " seconds");

 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are committing every new document, which is not necessary. It will run a lot faster if you change the `if (i % 100 == 0)` block to read

```
if (i % 100 == 0) {
    System.out.println(" Every 100 records flush it");
    solrCloudClient.commit(); // periodically flush
}
```

On my machine, this indexes your 500 records in 14 seconds. If I remove the `commit()` call from the `for` loop, it indexes in 7 seconds.

Alternatively, you can add a `commitWithinMs` parameter to the `solrCloudClient.add()` call:

```
solrCloudClient.add(doc, 15000);
```

This will guarantee your records are committed within 15 seconds, and also increase your indexing speed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me. I am busy with setting up 2 Solr instances, 1 zookeeper instance, so i struck with zookeeper znode for solr. I did not look at the code deep drive. thanks,  This is resolved.